# Angular driving one Select from another. Second select showing only a single result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code below and I am attempting to drive one select box from another but the subcategory select only shows one item at a time and it should show every item that has the parent category. For example, if Truck is selected in Category, Subcategory should show Telescope and Hazmat and If I choose Van, then subcategory would only have mini. What the heck am I doing wrong here?

```
        <select name="Category" ng-model="selectedCategory" 
           ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in categories | unique:'name' | orderBy:'name'" ng-change="">
          <option value="" disabled selected>All Categories</option>
        </select>


        <select name="SubCategory"  ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-options="item.id as item.subCategory for item in categories | filter:selectedCategory | orderBy:'subCategory'" >
          <option value="" disabled selected>All SubCategories</option>
        </select>



 $scope.selectedCategory = null;
      $scope.categories = [];
      $scope.$watch('selectedCategory', function() {
                $scope.selectedSubCategory = null;
              });



      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'test.php?option=com_ajax&type=Category&format=json',
        data: { }
    }).success(function (result) {
       $scope.categories = result;

    });
```

...

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Truck",
    "subCategory": "Telescope"
    },
    {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Truck",
    "subCategory": "Hazmat"
    },
    {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Van",
    "subCategory": "Mini"
    }
```

Comment: put it in a plnkr or fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the code I guess the ngModel `selectedCategory` will have the `item.id` and id is unique for all the items but you want to filter by `item.name` in the subcatagories

So one way will be to modify the parent select as below,

```
        <select name="Category" ng-model="selectedCategory" 
           ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in categories">
          <option value="">All Categories</option>
        </select>
```

Sample Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/E45B50eFmxRaep5WiWKW?p=preview

Comment: This is genius... Interesting thing is that is the filter scans the entirety of the text. So if I select Bucket as the Category, any Category object that has the bucket text in it will be displayed when I only want elements that only exist in the Bucket category. It would be great if I could specify what property to filter on in the child.

Comment: This is already taken care of impicitly as the first `selectedCategory` is linked to `item.name` selected so when you are filtering by `selectedCategory` in subcatagories you are actually filtering by `item.name`